# Preparing an array for model.predict() In tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to predict dog versus cats in my trained model. In my code, I load my trained model and load the images from a directory on my computer, and images load without an issue. In my small test set there are 5 cat and 5 dog images

When I run this code, It always predicts dog, but I can assure you there is not a problem in my model, It has 97% accuracy, which is pretty great. And by the way, when I explicitly test a cat image with directly putting the image.jpg in `model.predict()`, It predicts it right. I think the issue is that I put `resized_img` in `model.predict()`, I don't know how to put an array in `model.predict()`.

I am a complete newbie, I don't know if I am doing it right.

Any tip would be really helpful. Thanks!

```py
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]
IMG_SIZE = 200
TEST_DIR = r"C:\mydir\*.*"
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("catsvsdogspredict.model")


for file in glob.glob(TEST_DIR):
    img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    resized_img = resized_img.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
    prediction = model.predict(resized_img)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.title("Prediction: " + CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction)])
    plt.show()
```

Here is how I read the training images.

```py
training_data = []
def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category) #path to cats or dogs dir, string matching with file name
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

create_training_data()
print(len(training_data))
random.shuffle(training_data)
# creating arrays
X = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y = np.array(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code of the imagen preprocessing?

Maybe you train with normalization imagen, but predicting with normal image. You read Gray imagen, you train with RGB or Gray??

Try this or something similar, but need more information of your code:

```py
#Convert the image to numpy array and normalization.
resized_img = np.array([resized_img]) / 255.0
```

Comment: I use grayscale and yes, I have divided the image array on the training set to 255. I did what you suggested but it still predicts a cat as a dog on all images. I updated the thread with how I read the training images

Comment: is there anybody that can help?